# How can I make my buttons asociate with their picture

Tags: javascript, html, css

so I managed to create a slideshow with buttons for my website that automatically changes to the next page every X seconds ... The problem is that I want the buttons to be interactive, so when pressed to move my slideshow to a their specific images (For example pressing the second button to get me to the second image https://i.stack.imgur.com/i1a2j.jpg). I've tried to implement an on-click function for the buttons and search other variants but nothing seems to work
Here is my code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ro">
<head>
    <title>CarolandHouse</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="author" content="Penescu Carol-Marian">
    <meta name="description" content="Proiecte Case , Arhitectura , Modelare in AutoCAD">
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.1/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-+4zCK9k+qNFUR5X+cKL9EIR+ZOhtIloNl9GIKS57V1MyNsYpYcUrUeQc9vNfzsWfV28IaLL3i96P9sdNyeRssA==" crossorigin="anonymous" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/utilities.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"href="css/primapagina.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/showcase.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/cli.css">

</head>
<body>
    
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animejs/2.0.2/anime.min.js"></script>
    
    <div class ="main" >
        <div class="navbar bg-dark ">
        <div class="container flex lead py-1 ">
           <nav>
                <ul>
                    <l1><a href="index.html " class="ml16 flex container lead">Home</a></l1>
                    <li><a href="features.html" class="ml17 flex container lead">Features</a></li>
                    <li><a href="docs.html" class="ml18 flex container lead">Docs</a></li>
                </ul>   
        </nav>
            <div >
                <h1 class="ml5 ">
                    <span class="text-wrapper ">
                      <span class="line line1 "></span>
                      <span class="letters letters-left text-light">Caroland</span>
                      <span class="letters letters-right text-light">House</span>
                      <span class="line line2 "></span>
                    </span>
                  </h1>
                  
            </div>
            <div class="social sm">
                <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-facebook fa-2x"></i></a>
                <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-instagram fa-2x"></i></a>
                <a href="#" class="ml19 flex container" >Contact</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>

        
    <!-- Imagini slideshow -->
    <section class="bg-dark">
        <div class="slideshow-container">
        
        <div class="mySlides fade">
          
          <img src="imaginitest/imagine1birou.jpg" alt="#" >
          
        </div>
        
        <div class="mySlides fade">
          
          <img src="imaginitest/imagine1casa.jpg" alt="#"  >
          
        </div>
        
        <div class="mySlides fade">
          
          <img src="imaginitest/imagine1hotel.jpg"alt="#"  >
          
        </div>
        </div>
        lorem10
 <div style="text-align:center">
          <span class="dot"></span> 
          <span class="dot"></span> 
          <span class="dot"></span> 
        </div>
        </section>
  
     tempora tempore quasi deserunt autem nesciunt hic numquam illum voluptate?
   <!-- Cli -->
    <section class="cli">
        <div class="container grid">
            <img src="images/cli.png" alt="">
            <div class="card">
                <h3>Easy to use, cross platform CLI</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="card">
                <h3>Deploy in seconds</h3>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    
    

    <!-- Footer -->
    <footer class="footer bg-dark ">
        <div class="container flex lead py-1">
           <div class=" flex-basis-3">
               <h1>Despre</h1>
               <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Corporis voluptatum vel praesentium molestias consectetur ea consequuntur a quidem vitae iste?</p>
           </div> 
           <div class="flex-basis-3 text-center">
            <h1>CarolandHouse</h1>
            <p>Copyright &copy; 2021</p>
            </div>
            <div class=" flex-basis-3 text-right">
                <div class="align-better">
                   <span><a href="index.html">Home</a></span>
                   <span><a href="features.html">Features</a></span>
                   <span><a href="docs.html">Docs</a></span>
                </div>
                <div>
                  <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-facebook fa-2x"></i></a>
                  <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-instagram fa-2x"></i></a>
                </div>
            </div>
         </div>
    </footer>
    
    <script src="javascript/javascriptprincipal.js"></script>
    
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

I've updated the form of my code with a basic one

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
* {box-sizing: border-box;}
body {font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;}
.mySlides {display: none;}
img {vertical-align: middle;}

/* Slideshow container */
.slideshow-container {
  max-width: 1000px;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
}

/* Caption text */
.text {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 8px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

/* Number text (1/3 etc) */
.numbertext {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

/* The dots/bullets/indicators */
.dot {
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  margin: 0 2px;
  background-color: #bbb;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
}

.active {
  background-color: #717171;
}

/* Fading animation */
.fade {
  -webkit-animation-name: fade;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
  animation-name: fade;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fade {
  from {opacity: .4} 
  to {opacity: 1}
}

@keyframes fade {
  from {opacity: .4} 
  to {opacity: 1}
}

/* On smaller screens, decrease text size */
@media only screen and (max-width: 300px) {
  .text {font-size: 11px}
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Automatic Slideshow</h2>
<p>Change image every 2 seconds:</p>

<div class="slideshow-container">

<div class="mySlides fade">
  <div class="numbertext">1 / 3</div>
  <img src="img_nature_wide.jpg" style="width:100%">
  <div class="text">Caption Text</div>
</div>

<div class="mySlides fade">
  <div class="numbertext">2 / 3</div>
  <img src="img_snow_wide.jpg" style="width:100%">
  <div class="text">Caption Two</div>
</div>

<div class="mySlides fade">
  <div class="numbertext">3 / 3</div>
  <img src="img_mountains_wide.jpg" style="width:100%">
  <div class="text">Caption Three</div>
</div>

</div>
<br>

<div style="text-align:center">
  <span class="dot"></span> 
  <span class="dot"></span> 
  <span class="dot"></span> 
</div>

<script>
var slideIndex = 0;
showSlides();

function showSlides() {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.display = "none";  
  }
  slideIndex++;
  if (slideIndex > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}    
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
    dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
  dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
  setTimeout(showSlides, 2000); // Change image every 2 seconds
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That is a lot of code. It would definitely help me if you could narrow down the code to the problem. Maybe you can just write an html-page without navigation, etc. just your image / slideshow - check if with this minimal approach your problem still exists and then post the code here. This way it would be a lot easier for me to see what is happening and relevant and see if I can spot the error.

Comment: I've updated the code with another snippet only for the part with the slideshow animation , with it's javascript function ... I belive what I need to do is just update in a way the javascript so the buttons will redirect to their image , just should be the only thing

Comment: What buttons are you talking about? The dots? I see no code handling the click event of those dots. Please [edit] your question to remove the extra code (so only the focused code snippet remains) and add your attempt (based on the research you've done) to solve the issue.

Comment: Yes I am talking about the dots and I've tried to combine what I have with  what I saw in this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9Irz0c-6UGw but wasn't successfull , that's why I've asked the question so I can find a way to do it properly

Comment: So any ideas how to make it work ?